# Prompting User for input

Tags: java

I have the following code which should prompt the user to enter a string of numbers. The prompt appears, but the program does not take input.

Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong?

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string of numbers.  Start with \'-\' to quit.");

        String testNumber;
        testNumber = keyboard.next();

        char[] testArray = testNumber.toCharArray();
        if(testArray[0] == '-')
        {
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it "does not take input"?  Your program doesn't actually do anything with the input except immediately exit.

Comment: @azurefrog...thanks for responding.  It doesn't allow me to input anything.  It runs right through the system.in without taking input.

Comment: Not when I run it, it doesn't.  Adding debug statements, I can see it blocking on `keyboard.next()` until I input something.  How, exactly, are you running your program?

Comment: *note:  i've changed the order, swapping the Scanner declaration line with the system.out line.  If I'm understanding syntax correctly, I should get the prompt to enter printed (which I am getting), then get an opportunity to enter a response (which I am not).

Comment: I am building and running it in IntelliJ

Comment: I'm new to IntelliJ, perhaps I'm doing something incorrectly in my configuration.  It's not printing out to a console, it's just running in the message area below the text editor.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone.  This was just a bonehead error on my part.  I wasn't moving my cursor into the message area where the program was running.  Doh!

Answer (score 0):

sure it takes inputs, try printing the value of testnumber, you would see the value. Try `"System.out.print(testnumber)"` and you would see the inputted value.